# we created okta_group_memberships using terraform. we are creating multple users but we want only selected user

Tags: terraform, tuples, okta

We created okta users, and okta groups using terraform

This is variables.tf
used variable list object for users and groups

```
variable "users" {
  type = list(object
    ({
      first_name   = string
      last_name    = string
      email        = string
      organization = string
      role         = string
      team         = string
  }))
}

variable "groups" {
  type = list(object
    ({
      name        = string
      description = string
  }))
}
```

This is terraform.tfvars

```
groups = [
  { name = "dev", description = "This group for Devlopers" },
  { name = "qa", description = "This group for QA" },
  { name = "per", description = "This group for Per" }
  { name = "devops", description = "This group for Devops" }
]

users = [
  { first_name = "a", last_name = "a", email = "a@gmail.com", role = "Engineer", organization = "organization", team = ["dev"] },
  { first_name = "b", last_name = "b", email = "b@gmail.com", role = "Lead", organization = "organization", team = ["qa" },
  { first_name = "c", last_name = "c", email = "c@gmail.com", role = "Devloper", organization = "organization", team = ["devops" },
  { first_name = "d", last_name = "d", email = "d@gmail.com", role = "Engineer", organization = "organization", team = ["dev",},
  { first_name = "e", last_name = "e", email = "e@gmail.com", role = "Lead", organization = "organization", team = ["per"] },
  { first_name = "f", last_name = "f", email = "f@gmail.com", role = "Devloper", organization = "organization", team = ["dev" },
],
```

this is main.tf

```
locals {
  #groups
  dev_group         = [for dev in var.groups : dev if apollo.name == "dev"][0]
  devops_group       = [for devops in var.groups : devops if devops.name == "devops"][0]
  per_group         = [for per in var.groups : per if per.name == "per"][0]
  qa_group.         = [for qa in var.groups : qa if qa.name == "qa"][0]
 # users
  dev_user         = [for dev in var.users : dev if dev.team == "dev"][0]
  qa_user          = [for qa var.users : qa if qa.team == "qa"][0]
  per_user         = [for per var.users : per if per.team == "per"][0]
  devops_user.     = [for devops var.users : devops if devops.team == "devops"][0]
}
```

to get the values used for_each

```
resource "okta_group" "groups" {
  for_each    = { for group in var.groups : join("-", [group.name, group.description]) => group }
  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
}



resource "okta_user" "okta_user_add" {
  for_each = { for user in var.users : join("-", [user.first_name, user.last_name]) => user }

  title        = each.value.role
  email        = each.value.email
  first_name   = each.value.first_name
  last_name    = each.value.last_name
  login        = each.value.email
  organization = each.value.organization
}
```

when we are trying to get id we tried multiple things but it didn't work for us.
unable to get the group id and user id's

```
resource "okta_group_memberships" "b_member_group" {

  group_id = okta_group.groups[join("-", [local.dev.name, local.dev.description])].id
  users = [ okta_user.okta_user_add[join("-", [local.b_user.first_name, local.b_user.last_name])].id ]
}
```

**my question is**

When we are creating okta_group_memberships we are getting only one user from it. in locals i selected b_user select `b_user       = [for bin var.users : b if b.team == "b"][0]` This is working but it selecting only one user from it.

if i insert `[*]` i am getting error from it.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 55, in resource "okta_group_memberships" "b_member_group":
│   55:     okta_user.okta_user_add[join("-", [local.b_user.first_name, local.b_user.last_name])].id    
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.b_user is tuple with 4 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `[for bin var.users : b if b.team == "b"]` constructs the following:

```
[
  { first_name = "c", last_name = "c", email = "c@gmail.com", role = "Devloper", organization = "organization", okta_admin = false, team ="b" },
  { first_name = "d", last_name = "d", email = "d@gmail.com", role = "Engineer", organization = "organization", okta_admin = true, team = "b" },
  { first_name = "e", last_name = "e", email = "e@gmail.com", role = "Lead", organization = "organization", okta_admin = true, team ="b" },
  { first_name = "f", last_name = "f", email = "f@gmail.com", role = "Devloper", organization = "organization", okta_admin = false, team ="b" },
]
```

You then access the zeroth element of this list with `[0]`, which would return:

```
{ first_name = "c", last_name = "c", email = "c@gmail.com", role = "Devloper", organization = "organization", okta_admin = false, team ="b" }
```

This is why there is only one user returned from the value. You need to remove the `[0]` element accessor:

```
b_user = [for bin var.users : b if b.team == "b"]
```

You would also need to update your argument value correspondingly:

```
users = [ for b_user in local.b_user : okta_user.okta_user_add[join("-", [b_user.first_name, b_user.last_name])].id]
```

Comment: I have some queries regarding the above question. we have users. users are multiple team members. we have to filter by team. and add them to group members. according to that, I modified my question. teams and groups are both are same. can you please suggest to me the best answer?

Comment: @Veera You would need to ask a new question for that. Changing an answered question to a new unanswered question is not allowed on StackOverflow. I am sure we will assist you promptly with your new question once it is asked.